# Eclipse Mars Tomcat 8 server disappeared

Tags: eclipse, error-handling, tomcat8, sql-server-mars

I'm trying to define a Tomcat 8.5.16 server but everytime I use the 7 I get an error and when I go into preference to use the newer server it tells me the v8 installation is expecting an 8 server although I am pointing it to my tomcat 8.[image] Please help.[image]

I click OK and get "The Apache Tomcat installation at this directory is version 8.5.16.  A Tomcat 8.0 installation is expected."
This is under windows->preferences-> Adding a server.

Answer (score 0):

I think Tomcat 8.5.16 cannot be added as Tomcat 8.0.

See also:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=494936

You may have to upgrade your eclipse or apply a patch, for example,

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=262418&action=edit